# Laravel - Get sum of a column without querying to database more than once

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

My table structure is like this:

```
id      user_id     gift
1       1           1000
```

but now I want to move the `gift` to another table since the gift can be given to the users more than once in different dates. I have used `$user->gift` in many places in my project and I don't want to change the code. So I want to create a method in `User` model called `getGiftAttribute`. Inside this method I'm going to have the sum of the gifts. But now the problem is that each time that `$user->gift` is called in my code it queries the database, but I want it to be called once. As previously if I used `$user->gift`, it would query only once. So how can I get the sum of `gift` which is in another table without querying more than once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really don't want to change your code **at all** and get the sum of gifts at multiple places with only one query, you could do something like this:

```php
class User extends Models {
    protected $sumGifts = null;

// [...]

    public function getGiftAttribute()
    {
       if($this->sumGifts == null){
           $this->sumGift = $this->gifts()->sum('gift'); 
           // or whatever you use to retrieve the sum of all gifts
       }

       return $this->sumGifts;
    }
}
```

Doing so, you are storing the sum of all gifts inside a property of your User model and therefore the query will be executed only once, when you first use `$user->gift`. All subsequent calls to `$user->gift` will return the sum previously stored in the `sumGifts` property.

---

It will work, however, I think a better approach would be to wisely use relationships and eagerloading.

Comment: If I could give you +2, I would :) Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you add the `gifts` to the user as a relationship, then laravel should automatically only query the gifts table once per user.
If you want to get the gifts for multiple users and only want to access the `gifts` table once, then you can use [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading).

For example, you could write `->with('gifts')` in your users query.